# Embedded block editor in block editor

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to create UI in gutenberg block editor where main Editor interface picks persons from the database of personnel (separate custom table in MySQL), and each person has button beneath, which when pressed opens a 'window' where short biography could be entered.

Data about which persons are picked are saved in regular page, but biography for each person should be saved in custom post type 'biographies', so it can be shown on more than one page, as popup and also as separate page.

I decided that best approach would be to embed another instance of block-editor, similar to reusable blocks. However, I can not get it to save content and to show proper blocks in inserter (it shows blocks from context of main editor)

This is what I came with so far (code is component which opens editor instance popup on a button and closes it with another button in popup:

```
 /**
 * Component for entering biography
 */

import { BlockEditorProvider, BlockList, WritingFlow, ObserveTyping } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Button } from '@wordpress/components';
import { useState, useEffect, useSelect } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { EntityProvider, useEntityBlockEditor, useEntityId  } from '@wordpress/core-data';

// const TABLE = 'tla_mit_lecturers_biography';


const BiographyModal = ({ name, showButton, postID, setPostID }) => {
    const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false);
    const [ blocks, onInput, onChange ] = useEntityBlockEditor(
        'postType',
        'biographies',
        { id: postID }
    );
    const retrievedID = useEntityId( 'postType', 'biographies' );
    useEffect(() => setPostID(retrievedID), [retrievedID])
    const editorSettings = {
        allowedBlockTypes: ['core/paragraph']
    }

    const editorInstance =
            // <EntityProvider
            //  kind="postType"
            //  type="biographies"
            //  id={postID}
            // >
                <BlockEditorProvider
                    value={ blocks }
                    onChange={ onChange }
                    onInput={ onInput }
                    // selection={ selection }
                    settings={ editorSettings }
                    useSubRegistry={ true }
                >
                    <WritingFlow>
                        <ObserveTyping>
                            <BlockList />
                        </ObserveTyping>
                    </WritingFlow>
                </BlockEditorProvider>;
            // </EntityProvider>;

    const modal =
        <div className="biography-modal">
            <h3>{ `Životopis ${ name }` }</h3>
            {editorInstance}
            <Button isDefault onClick={ () => setIsOpen(false) }>
                Završi
            </Button>
        </div>;


    return (
        <div className="biography-module">
            {
                (showButton || isOpen) &&
                <Button isDefault disabled={isOpen} onClick={ () => setIsOpen( true ) }>Uredi životopis</Button>
            }
            { isOpen && modal }
        </div>
    )
}

export default BiographyModal;
```

I am also not sure if block editor should be wrapped in `EntityProvider` or not, it seems to do nothing. Although editor appears and typing inside is possible, it gives error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "blocks", record is undefined`. I guess it could be because `BlockEditorProvider` and `useEntityBlockEditor` operate on different registries.

Comment: I don't think that's how reusable blocks work, this approach looks like a dead end, and I can foresee lots of data store level conflicts and issues with plugins and code that rely on the `wp.data` global.

Comment: Confirmed, reusable blocks use a dedicated block type, a tonne of complicated redux store adjustments from `@wordpress/reusable-blocks`, and undocumented hook named `useEntityBlockEditor` to insert inner blocks that actually come from a completely different post. It does not use an independent/separate editor instance. The data store adjustments handle some of the state management of wether you're in a reusable block editing mode or not https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/2bbb589b1c8449d0ddd3a922a42c5dc12eda2fbf/packages/core-data/src/entity-provider.js#L147

Comment: I would also avoid "opening a window" wether that's a lightbox/model or an actual dedicated window. From what I see this is not a simple/easy task to figure out

Comment: Could your "Edit Bio" button just link to the edit page of the custom post type?

Comment: @Phil I thought about that, but it is not the same user experience.